# Wordpress Query one record set but sorting from a value from a. second query set

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I have five custom post types:

Persons (each record having a Title, first name, last name)

Show (each record having year perfomed, opening night, closing night and category taxomny)

Position (each record being the name of a position such as Director, Designer, etc along with two different number fields which I will use for sorting in diferent situation)

Cast (title being the role acted in play, the person associated with playing the character and the associated Show the role was perfroemd in)

Crew (the Crew Position Title, person's name and associated show)

For Each Person, I have single layout lyaout which will show all the Shows that Person performed in as Cast member and then all the Shows that person worked as a Crew member on.

The Query I have for displaying all the Cast roles on this Person record is:

```
//Get this person's post ID
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// cast query
$cast_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'cast',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'actor',
                'value'     => $post_id,
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        ),
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'       => $post_title, // this meta field's value
        'order'          => 'ASC'
));
```

The query works but the problem is sorting. I wish to sort on "year" field, not within the Cast record by within the 'year' field of the associated Show. So changing the meta_key' to => 'year' will not work. I am assume I need to create a secondary array somehow? I have looking in the variosu forum here and havent found it yet. Any some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are Shows related to cast or actor IDs?

Comment: Sorry for the somewhat long reply. but it helps me talk it through.  Using Advanced Custom Fields, The SHOW custom Post Type has fields:Year, WrittenBy, and other fields specific to each SHOW
The POSITION Custom Post has fields: SortID, Bio Sort ID , (both fields are numbers)
The CAST CPT has The Post Title (which is the Character Role), Actor (which is a Post Object field pulling from the PERSONS CPT) which is returned by ACF as Post ID and a field named "show" (also Post Object returning a value of Post ID referring the records on the SHOW CPT).

Comment: To clarify: are cast or actor IDs stored on Shows?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, no. The CAST CPT stores the data (associated SHOW Post ID) within its record, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: a custom SQL query using `$wpdb` (not recommended), or getting results from `WP_Query` and then processing the results in PHP.

Here's are the steps necessary:

1. Get all Cast posts for specified actor
2. Iterate over the Cast posts:

   1. Get ID of Show assigned to current Cast post
   2. Get year of Show from post meta (using Show ID)
   3. Store Show's year as entry in array of years
3. Sort the array of Cast posts by the array of show years

Untested:

```php
// Get the IDs of Cast posts for specified actor.
$cast_for_actor = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'cast',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array( ... ),
    'no_found_rows'  => false,
) );

// Array of Cast IDs keyed by year of Show.
$years = array();

// Get the shows for each cast member.
foreach ( $cast_for_actor->posts as $cast ) {
    $show_id = get_post_meta( $cast_for_actor->ID, '{meta_key}', true );

    if ( empty( $show_id ) ) {
        $years[] = '9999';
        continue;
    }

    $show_year = absint( get_post_meta( $show_id, '{meta_key}', true ) );

    if ( empty( $show_year ) ) {
        $years[] = '9999';
        continue;
    }

    $years[] = $show_year;
}

array_multisort( $cast_for_actor->posts, $years, SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL );

while ( $cast->have_posts() ) {
    $cast->the_post();

    ...
}
```

Note that if the arrays are different sizes, the sorting will fail, which is why the code above adds `9999` to the array if the show ID or year is empty. If you want cast without a clear Show year to be listed first, change `9999` to `0`.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow :)

Comment: Our Year field is actually in the format of 2020-2021, 2021-2022, 2022-2023, etc. So Should I be setting the $years string to 99999999 ?

Comment: I don't think so, as range will be a string rather than numeric; updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also in the 'meta_query' where ... is I assuming in this array wil be my original. meta query array arguments from my example?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.